# Search a cell value in another workbook tab and print data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement where in , I have a set of data stored in "Sheet1" column A as below

```
Cat
Dog
Mouse
Horse
```

And I have another workbook  - "Animaldetails.xlsx" where I have several tabs which holds "Cat","Dog","Mouse","Horse" and several other names as well

I need to search all values from my "sheet1" into "Animaldetails.xlsx" tabs and copy all the data present in each tab into seperate sheet - "sheet2"

Coming to what I have done , I have tried .Find method but I was able to do only for 1 cell and not for multiple values. I can able to search in sheet but I want to search in tabs of workbook

I'm aware this can be achieved using `INDIRECT` function but I'm looking to do it from VBA

Comment: Are `"Cat","Dog"` in the name of the tab (worksheet) or has that to be searched in cells (data of a worksheet)?

Comment: Those are the names of the worksheet in another workbook

Comment: Then you can just use these variables as worksheet names and use that object as a reference pulling data from a range.

Comment: @user1838000 are the names of your sheets **exactly** `Cat` or `Dog` or are they just containing these words and actually named `Somthing with Cat in it`, `xyDoggyZ`? If it is the first one then my answer is not the fastest way to do that.

Comment: it has exactly the name .

Comment: @user1838000 check my answer again. I added a solution for exact names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a worksheet with a name conaiting `Cat` you need to loop through all worksheets an compare their name against `Cat`.

Example:

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Set Wb = Application.Workbooks("Animaldetails.xlsx")  'or set any other workbook

Dim Ws As Worksheet
For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets 'loop through all worksheets
    If Ws.Name Like "*Cat*" Then  'note the asterisks as placeholder
        'the worksheet Ws has `Cat` in its name
    End If
Next Ws
```

To not only check for `Cat` but all the others too, you need another loop to check each Ws for all names in the list:

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Set Wb = Application.Workbooks("Animaldetails.xlsx")  'or set any other workbook

Dim TestNameList() As Variant
TestNameList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Value 'adjust range to your data

Dim Ws As Worksheet
For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets 'loop through all worksheets
    Dim TestName As Variant
    For Each TestName in TestNameList
        If Ws.Name Like "*" & TestName & "*" Then
            'the worksheet Ws has TestName in its name
            Debug.Print Ws.Name & " has " & TestName & " in its name."
            'your copy actions here
            'Ws.Range("A1").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") 'adjust to your needs

            'if every sheetname can only match one of the names then you can exit for here to fasten the code
            Exit For
        End If
    Next TestName
Next Ws
```

---

If the names of your worksheets are **exactly** `Cat` and `Dog` then it us much easier to use them directly:

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Set Wb = Application.Workbooks("Animaldetails.xlsx")  'or set any other workbook

Dim TestNameList() As Variant
TestNameList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Value 'adjust range to your data

Dim TestName As Variant
For Each TestName in TestNameList
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next  'next line throws error if sheet name does not exist
    Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets(TestName)
    On Error Goto 0  're-enable error reporting

    If Not Ws Is Nothing Then
        'Ws is now your worksheet with `TestName`

        'your copy actions here
        'Ws.Range("A1").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") 'adjust to your needs
    Else
        MsgBox "Worksheet '" & TestName & "' not found."
    End If
Next TestName
```